# Criar painel com o centro no ponto do clique do usuário

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

Preciso criar um `Panel` em um `Form` Ficando mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clicar com o mouse no `Form` criar o `Panel` pegando a localização do clique e criar o `Panel` centralizado.

Fiz assim:

```
Panel panel = new Panel();

private void criarLabel()
{
      panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
      panel.Visible = true;
      this.grid.Controls.Add(panel);
}
private void grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     criarLabel();
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Consigo criar o Panel.

Comment: Só não consigo centralizar ele no local do Click. Meu panel tem uma altura fixa

Comment: É que eu acho que você esqueceu alguma parte da sua pergunta. Vamos lá, você quer clicar numa área da tela e criar um panel que fique com o "centro" na parte que o usuário clicou, certo?

Comment: Tem como colocar o código que você tem até o momento?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta.

Comment: Isso mesmo @jbueno..

Comment: Gostei da pergunta, só acho que ela poderia estar melhor escrita, de qualquer forma +1.

Comment: @jbueno pode alterar a perguntar para que a mesma fique melhor escrita!

Comment: Você conseguiu fazer? @Lilloh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque esse bloco de código no evento [`MouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx) do `Form` (ou do controle que terá o `Panel` adicionado).

```
var panel = new Panel
{
    BackColor = Color.Black,
    Height = 100,
    Width = 200
};

panel.Location = new Point(e.X - (panel.Width / 2), e.Y - (panel.Height / 2));

this.Controls.Add(panel);
```